# How i can insert string data to diagrams in chart.js

Tags: node.js, socket.io, chart.js

I want to real time visualise my received data from socket.io on charts.js. My recevied data is String, have 18 values and looks like: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,...,18] and have Xaxis like: A,B,C,D,E and when i push this data it doesnt show on charts

My receiving function

```
            socket.on('temp', function(data) { 
                console.log(data.temp);
                document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = data.date; 
                chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
                        dataset.data.push(data.temp); 
                    });
                chart.update();
            });
```

My chart code

```
  var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
                // The type of chart we want to create
                type: 'line',

                // The data for our dataset
                data: {
                labels: ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","J","K","L", "M", "N","O","P","R"],
                datasets: [{
                    label: "Swiatlo",
                    borderColor: "#FF5733",
                    data: [],
                    fill: false,
                    pointStyle: 'circle',
                    backgroundColor: '#3498DB',
                    pointRadius: 5,
                    pointHoverRadius: 7,
                    lineTension: 0,
                }]
                },

                // Configuration options go here
                options: {}

            });
```

So how can i visualise them in that way?  Fist value = A, Second = B...

Answer (score 0):

The code that you show us seems right, the only thing that you need is to shift the data in the dataset before adding the new value, like:

```
socket.on('temp', function(data) { 
    console.log(data.temp);
    document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = data.date; 
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data.shift();
        dataset.data.push(data.temp); 
    });
    chart.update();
});
```